# How can implement hide/show button in webview as gmail has on reply message in android application?

Tags: android, html, hide, reply

How can implement hide/show button in webview as gmail has on reply message?
Then you push reply message, message are hidden in "..." button.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Two textviews with click visibility for collapse and expand.

Comment: can I do it via Javascript?

Comment: @Slava Vir may be you can i havent tried

Comment: Yes, I just implemented by adding simple button in layout between them.